# Releasing all references to the Component after calling Dispose

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, garbage-collection

Regarding the `Dispose()` method of the `Component` class MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says -

`The Dispose method leaves the Component in an unusable state. After calling Dispose, you must release all references to the Component so the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the Component was occupying.`

Now let's say, I have the following code -

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Show();

        //do something with form2            

        form2.Dispose();

        ???  ???  ???
        //form2 = null;           
    }
}
```

And let's say, form2 holds some Unmanaged resources that I need to be released immediately *and* of course, I want form2 to be garbage collected properly. So, how exactly should I `release all references to the Component` after calling `Dispose()` on form2? Do I need to set `form2 = null;` or something? Please advise. Thanks beforehand.

**EDIT :**

[**@Ed S.**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053/ed-s)

You mentioned -

`even if it were scoped to the method it would be free for garbage collection as soon as the method exits`

Can you please tell what exactly happens to the object `form2` in the following case?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowForm2();
    }

    private void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

The method `ShowForm2` exits, but the `form2` object is definitely not being garbage-collected. It's still showing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes, setting the only reference to `null` works, but your example is contrived.  In well written code you would have just created a `Form2` instance local to the function:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        // do something with form2
    }
}
```

Now you don't have anything to worry about because you kept your object's scope as narrow as possible.

You don't want live references to `Dispose`d objects because it opens you up to using them after they are disposed. I write a fair bit of C# and don't ever explicitly set variables to null for this purpose.  You can manage object lifetimes in a more deterministic way.

EDIT:

Per your edit and question:

> The method ShowForm2 exits, but the form2 object is definitely not being garbage-collected. It's still showing.

Yes, in this case the form cannot be GC'd until it is closed (and you're also failing to call `Dispose()` on it.) That is because a GC "root" still exists for the form, though it is not visible in your code.

The correct statement is that an object is eligible for GC when it is no longer being used by the application. A more in depth look can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

Comment: hummm...that makes sense, using the `using` block. But a `using` block only ensures that when you leave that block form2's Dispose() will get called, and nothing else. My question is about the second part, how do you release this reference to form2? My event hand method might not be just end there.

Comment: Sorry I get this, the form2 object is scoped within the `using` block, & not within the entire EventHandler method. My bad. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NerotheZero: Yep, exactly, though even if it were scoped to the method it would be free for garbage collection as soon as the method exits.  Glad to help.

Comment: Please see the `EDIT` section. I've added a further query. Thanks.

Comment: @NerotheZero: Added a bit of info. As an aside, when someone answers your question, it is encouraged to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: W.T.H...I accepted your answer, & it was marked as Accepted!!! Doing it again, no worries :)